# how often are websphere mq log records flushed to disk in a channel batch

Tags: ibm-mq

Assuming each msg matches to a single TX, and a `batch` can contain multiple msgs. Question is, how often does QM writes those log records to disk, on both SDR and RCVR sides? For instance, if we `batche`s contains 50 msgs each, does that mean QM writes to disk on both sides 50 times, or there are some optimization nobs we can tune to avoid/reduce such io overhead.

A little background

We use WebsphereMQ (7.1.0.3) for QReplication, and frequently hit max MQ-transfer-rate at about `8.33 batch/sec` (or 120ms per `batch`). SDR chstatus report `NETTIME`~=24ms, ping time around 20ms, so seems like about 100ms spent per `batch` on both QMs together. The average `batch` size during those periods of time are at 100 (yes, it max out at `BATCHSZ`). Average `batch` size is a little less than 180KB, or about 1.8KB/msg.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the storage replicated on one or both ends?

Comment: Nope, at least not synchronously (need to check with storage team, but can't imagine we have it .....), and i assume you are referring to `storage level replication`?

Comment: MAX_TRANS is the number of messages to put to mq before a commit. If local storage on q capture side is a bottle neck this allows you to batch up multiple messages per commit. The link you sent says: The maximum number of database transactions that are replicated in an MQ commit interval.
So if it is 100 then q capture will put up to 100 mq messages every COMMIT_INTERVAL (default 500ms).

Comment: That setting would control disk writes by db2.  Batch size controls disk writes by sdr and rcvr.  All for persistent messages.

Comment: Max_trans may not help us out, as our transaction rate is approaching over 700tx/sec, or 700msg/sec, that needs to be replicated. In fact, we somehow set max_trans to 128, but doesn’t look like this value takes effect.... for us 1ms for 2 writes doesn’t seem unexpected.....

Comment: But regardless of how fast we put msg onto XMITQ, should we expect _every_ msg in the `batch` write to disk (at least) once on SDR side, and once on RCVR side? Still feel i'm missing something obvious, i think i read from ibmmq performance report of much higher throughput (of course hardware may be different...) than 1K msg/sec for 2KB persisted msg transmission in a single channel ...

Comment: Forgot to mention we do use default `LogBufferPages` which may (or may not) be a limiting factor, considering sometimes TX-size can be huge. We do allocate more than enough logfiles (i think), specifically `LogPrimaryFiles=210`/`LogSecondaryFiles=200`/`LogFilePages=16384`, compare to our MQ-transfer rate at less than around 833 msg/sec, or 1.5MB/sec...

Comment: Ran across this blog that explains some things about batch: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/c4142f9d-6cf1-44ef-a44a-b09428ad96d1/entry/If_I_want_to_do_packet_trace_of_an_MQ_channel_which_end_should_I_trace?lang=en_us

Answer (score 2):

All messages in a batch are transferred in 1 transaction, so the message channel agent will open 1 transaction on the sender and 1 on the receiver side to get and put all the messages in the batch. This transaction is committed when the batch size or the batch interval is exhausted.

Comment: Is it possible insufficient SDR-/RCV-bufferSize introduces extra disk flush for a big batch? We use v7.0.1 (on linux) without specifiying any additional TCP stanza. According to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q119250_.htm, the default 32Kb (4KB?) would be used. Our avg msg-size is around 2KB, so sounds like the tcp buffer would be full every 2 msg. if we have disk flush every 2 msg (and we constantly achive 100msg/batch.....) instead of once per batch, that may explain our MQ-transfer throuput throttle....

Comment: Well, according to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q018990_.htm the default (Rcv)RcvBuffSz for previous version (in our case 7.1.0.3) is more likely to be 32KB, not 4KB....

Comment: Naively i would guess the answer is no, but just in case.... wouldn't be surprised in log flush only happens when logBuffer is full, and we use the default 2MB, which seems big enough for us (yes, we are thinking about maximizing it next, we are not constraint by memory at all and can afford the max of 16MB).

Comment: also, how would NETTIME look like for this channel, assuming ping time of 20ms, batchSize=100, all TCP stanza uses default value (32K byte), with avg-msg-size=2K byte. Our observed NETTIME (during the period when achieved batchSz=100) stays around 24ms, which doesn't suggest additional round-trip happened....

Comment: Ok, i think i may find the answer. NETTIME only measures the duration between "end of batch" and "received ACK" on SDR side, minus duration to process CMIT on RCVR side. So the RRT sending batch over is not really measured/included in NETTIME.

Comment: ref. V9 KC seems explaining this in more details https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q038100_.html